# Blocked to view Protractor HTML Report from Robot Report HTML files in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, protractor, report, robotframework

I am trying to view the Protractor HTML Report from a particular folder from the Robot HTML report from Jenkins.

Robot Code:

```
*** Settings ***
 Metadata    View UI report1      [${CURDIR}..${/}..${/}..${/}..${/}reports${/}IDGenerate_${timestp}${/}protractor-report.html | IDGenearte_Report1]
```

When I open this link in new tab from JENKINS with help of robot report I get issues like **about:blank#blocked**   not sure what to do?

But I have protractor html report generated inside report folder

can anyone guide on how to show the protractor report from Jenkins using Robot Report using Meta data

Comment: Can you open the report from the report folder? Certain Jenkins settings can block contents like Java script, might worth to check if it is something similar.
Does the link correct if you inspect it in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I can open manually in chrome. the only issue with an opening from jenkins

Comment: What should be the correct URL and what is the URL that is in the robot report, if you inspect the DOM?

Comment: I guess the Robot Framework log.html and report.html files are in the `reports` folder. While the protractor-report.html is in the `reports/IDGenerate_timestp` folder. If so try to define the metadata like this: `Metadata    View UI report1      [IDGenerate_${timestp}${/}protractor-report.html|IDGenearte_Report1]`